# Why No response from Google Invisible recaptcha?

Tags: php, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

Trying to achieve Google invisible recaptcha, but **I am not getting any response after verification.**

**Here is my code:**

invisible_recaptcha.php   (form)

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Recaptcha Demo</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script>
        function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById("i-recaptcha").submit();
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <!-- FORM GOES HERE -->
        <form id='i-recaptcha' action="process_recaptcha.php" method="post">
            <label for="fname">First Name*</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required autofocus><br><br>

            <label for="lname">Last Name*</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required><br><br>

            <label for="email">Email Address*</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required><br><br>

            <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXmy_site_keyXXXXXXXXX" data-size="invisible" data-callback="onSubmit">
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

process_recaptcha.php (verify the recaptcha)

```
<?php
// Checks if form has been submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    function post_captcha($user_response) {
        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
            'secret' => 'XXXXXX_my_secret_key_XXXXXXXXX',
            'response' => $user_response
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        //echo $user_response."<br><br><br><br>". $fields_string;exit;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

    // Call the function post_captcha
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    if (!$res['success']) {
        // What happens when the reCAPTCHA is not properly set up
        echo 'reCAPTCHA error: Check to make sure your keys match the registered domain and are in the correct locations. You may also want to doublecheck your code for typos or syntax errors.';
    } else {
        // If CAPTCHA is successful...

        // Paste mail function or whatever else you want to happen here!
        echo '<br><p>CAPTCHA was completed successfully!</p><br>';
    }
} ?>
```

**It always gives me this message:** 
reCAPTCHA error: Check to make sure your keys match the registered domain and are in the correct locations. You may also want to doublecheck your code for typos or syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this One

```
       try {
        //Get google capcha details
        if ($site_details['google_captcha_secret_key'] != '') {
            $site_key = $site_details['google_captcha_secret_key'];
        } else {
            $site_key = GOOGLE_CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY;
        }
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $data = ['secret' => $site_key,
            'response' => $captcha,
            'remoteip' => $this->userIpAddress];

        $options = [
            'http' => [
                'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            ]
        ];

        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        return json_decode($result)->success;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like it will work for me. Will mark this as ANSWER once I apply it to my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you double-check your code over for syntax errors. You are missing the left quote around your site key. You also have an extra parenthesis where it says json_decode.

Finally, you don't need to separate it into two PHP files if you are going to use this condition:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

So the php code in process_recaptcha.php can be embedded in invisible_recaptcha.php. You would then have to change the form's action attribute to itself (invisible_recaptcha.php). The condition will check if the form has been submitted yet. If is has, it will process your recaptcha code, if not, it will skip it.

Comment: That's fine. The single quote is missed during the Question formation, and making separate files or making single file is not going to solve my issue. Fixed the typo mistake in Question.